# Subsea Pipeline Data for the North Sea

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I have been looking for a vector file containing sub sea pipeline data in the North Sea, without much success. Any hints? (I have to be clear, pipelines only -no cables-)

Comment: Have you tried the [European Union data portal](https://data.europa.eu/euodp/data/dataset?q=pipeline&ext_boolean=all&sort=)? The dataset descriptions are sometimes a little vague, so I can't be sure if they have what you're looking for. You'll probably have to download some of the data sets to see what they are.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had a look, but was not able to find what I was looking for...